# How to install PortAudio and run a program in the RaspBerry Pi

Tags: linux, testing, installation, raspberry-pi, portaudio

I want to use PortAudio with my Raspberry Pi. I have followed the instructions of the PortAudio documentation (for Linux) and I have installed PortAudio sucessfully, but then when I try to test one of the example programs (the way the documentation says), it tells me: "cannot find -ljack".

I'm very new to Linux, but I love programming and I really want to be able to use PortAudio on my Raspi, I would really appreciate if you could give me a detailed explanation on how to run a program using PortAudio in the Raspi.

Comment: It appears that you may have compiled PortAudio to use the Jack interface.  (Or, you are running an example that also uses Jack.)  You either need to recompile PortAudio to use ALSA or install Jack.

Comment: Ok how can I do that?, I would really appreciate more help

Comment: Without knowing your exact setup and what you want to accomplish it is hard to give specific advice.  Here are the instructions for building PortAudio on Linux:  http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html.  If I were you I'd do some google searching on Raspberry Pi and PortAudio.  This might shed some light on your issue: http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=16103.0

Comment: it's been a long time. My exact setup would be gcc/g++ compiler, os raspbian, hardware raspberry pi 2 model b. thanks for the help

Comment: The output of `configure` should tell you which libraries PortAudio is being compiled with.  PortAudio is a wrapper around lower level audio libraries.  PortAudio can be configured to use OSS, ALSA, or JACK.  You need to determine which subsystem is install on your version of Raspian and run the example program accordingly.  It may just work if you remove `-ljack` from the command to run the example.